# calling controller from method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing a web site using MVC 3 razor, in which I have the following situation:

1. A controller method:

```
public ActionResult MyControllerMethod(int parameter){
    ''go to bd a do some staff
    IList<My_Custom> datafromDB = MyService.GetData(parameter);           

    'returns to my string tuped view
    return View(datafromDB );
}
```

2. A strong typed view in which I use JavaScript:

```
       @model IList<My_Custom>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
         function getData()
         { 
           var parameter = document.getElementById('myParamater').value;  
    
           $.get('/MyController/MyControllerMethod/' + parameter, function (data) {
                                   
              loadData();
    
           }
           );
       }
       
        function loadData() 
        { 
          clearData();
              
          datos = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));  
          
          //do some stuff with datos
          
        }
    
        </script>
```

The JavaScript call to the controller works fine but my problem is that the string typed view seems like is not taking the new value for the @model, so keeps loading the same information.

Although I have debugged the action controller and it returns different data every time.
So is there any way to refresh the Model value of a string typed view?

I also tried to process the data value of that line

```
$.get('/MyController/MyControllerMethod/' + parameter, function (data) {
```

but I wasn't successful doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action return view, that's why nothing works. How your code works:

- Load data in action, then generate view with json on the page
- Send requst to the server and receive `html` with `json` (all this data are in memory),
  then you access `json` from first step

How it must work:

- Create view
- Send request to the server (another method, that returning `Json`)
- Access `data`

```
    public ActionResult YourJsonAction(int parameter)
    {
        IList datafromDB = MyService.GetData(parameter);
        return Json(datafromDB, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    function getData() 
    {  
       var parameter = $('#myParamater').val();   
       $.get('/MyController/YourJsonAction/' + parameter, function (data) { 
          //data from YourJsonAction
       }); 
    }
```